# Date format on security.blogoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, date-format, blog-overflow

The date format on http://security.blogoverflow.com is ambigious. Can we have a month name in there as in the UK 07-06-11 is 7th June. (The year is ambiguous too, though that won't be a problem for another 89 years.)

Comment: I would have guessed that we used the ISO standard date format (YYYY-MM-DD). I'm surprised to see that that's not the case.

Comment: +1, excellent point, and while this is being fixed can we do the same to the Gaming blog as well please?

Answer (score 5):

I missed this when it was posted, my bad on the delay. ):

I've changed the date format to `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: When did it change to `Mon DD 'YY, `?