# Wrong date format on Blog Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

If you look at the [Seasoned Advice blog](http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/) main page, each article shows a date:

[image: Screenshot of date on Cooking.SE blog]

However, the administrative interface is set to use ISO dates:

[image: admin interface showing Y-m-d format]

The US-specific format is confusing, as Europeans write day-month-year instead of month-day-year. It has [confused at least Szabolcs](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4947595#4947595). Unfortunately, it seems that its hardcoded somewhere.

Please make the article date display respect the setting in the admin interface.

Comment: This is actually [a regression](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97746/date-format-on-security-blogoverflow-com)

Comment: @TimStone maybe it happened when they switched us off sketchy? Not sure.

Comment: Seems like a likely explanation. Certainly confusing though, hopefully it'll get patched up quickly.

Comment: Can't we just have the first? That way it is clear to **everybody.**

Comment: The first is clear, @BryanDunsmore, but also a bit awkward to read. I'd prefer "13th June, 2012", which better matches my speech patterns. (It doesn't match them perfectly: I'd say *the thirteenth of June, 2012*, but I'm happy that [speech and writing diverge in this area](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/81549/1696).)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The format for the date was hard-coded instead of pulling from the setting.  This has been changed and should display as Y-m-d (per the setting) from now on (once the cache clears up).